# Imprimir um array com varios dados de um select, uma única vez

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Eu tenho um *array* que recebe precisamente 18 valores. Cada "chave" desse *array* é um horário e cada valor deste é uma consulta SQL. 
Eu passo este *array* para um arquivo json para trazer os dados objetos que eu preciso. O problema é que este *array* imprime várias vezes e eu só preciso que  imprima uma vez com todos os selects.

```
.... action....

$selectDezenove = Doctrine::getTable('Atendimentos')->createQuery('a')
                                ->where('time(a.data_hora) =', $this->horarios ); 
    $this->horarios = array();
        $this->horarios["08:20"] = $selectDezenove;
        $this->horarios["08:40"] = $selectDezenove;
.....
.... json.php ...

 foreach($horarios as $horario => $atendimento)
{
    foreach($records as $atendimento)
    {
        if( date("H:i", strtotime($atendimento->getDataHora())) === $horario )
        {
         $list[] =
                '{'."\n".
                '   "id":'.  $atendimento->getId().','."\n".      
                ' "cell":'."\n". 
                '           ['."\n".
                    '                   "'.$atendimento->getId().'",'."\n". 
                    '                   "'.$horario.'",'."\n".
                         ++dados+++
        }
        else 
        {
            $list[] =
                '{'."\n".
                '   "id":'.$atendimento->getId().','."\n".      
                ' "cell":'."\n". 
                '           ['."\n".
                    '                   "",'."\n". 
                    '                   "'.$horario.'",'."\n". 
                   ++dados++
         }
         if($atendimento == NULL )
         {
           $list[] =
                    '{'."\n".
                    '   "id":'.$atendimento->getId().','."\n".      
                    ' "cell":'."\n". 
                    '           ['."\n".
                        '                   "",'."\n". 
                        '                   "'.$horario.'",'."\n".
                        +++dados+++
          }
        }
       }
      }
     ....... fim json .....
```

O problema é que o meu resultado está sendo impresso muitas vezes, tipo para cada `select` que retornar 1 resultado, está imprimindo a lista com todos os *arrays*, se eu tiver 2 resultados irá imprimir 1 *array* de 18 posições 2 vezes, se tiver 3 resultados, 1 *array* com 18 posições 3 vezes ... e assim por diante.

O que pode estar errado nisso? Estou trabalhando com o framework symfony 1.4, com ORM Doctrine 1.4

Comment: Isso não está diretamente relacionado à sua pergunta, mas cogite a possibilidade de usar `json_encode` no lugar de concatenar esse monte de strings — seu código vai ficar mais eficiente e mais seguro.

Comment: Fico me perguntando porque não usar `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

O que ele imprimi são as informações do array $records, o que pode está acontecendo é que o array $horarios é maior que o array $records e o mesmo está dentro do foreach que percore $horarios. 
Por exemplo o array $horarios tem 2 posições, ou seja, seu foreach vai rodar duas vezes. E o seu array $horarios que está dentro desse foreach só tem uma posição e como ele está dentro do primeiro foreach que faz o loop duas vezes ele vai repetir o seu resultado.

P.S: Não sei se deu pra entender mas espero ter ajudado!